# Linux alias question

Tags: linux, alias, arguments

I want to create an alias for this command "rmi" so that if I execute

```
rmi File.txt
```

it will actually execute

```
ls * | grep -v File.txt | xargs rm -rf
```

Basically I want to reorder arguments.

Comment: you failed to mention which UNIX shell you are using... sh, csh, tcsh, bash, zsh, ... ?

Answer (score 3):

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ls * | grep -v $1 | xargs rm -rf
```

-Save this as rmi.

-do: `chmod a+x rmi`

-Then add to path.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with an alias.  You'll need to write a script.

Comment: +1 Note that it's not impossible, it's just not possible using alias. This could be poor terminology on OP's part, being that alias has a specific meaning.

Comment: you don't need a script, you can write a shell function which is as easy as writing an alias.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a script. Instead of alias, you can write a shell function:

```
myfunc() {
  ls * | grep -v $1 | xargs rm -rf
}

# usage: myfunc <filename>
```

store it in ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc, or a separate aliases file, eg. using the idiom

```
test -f ~/.zaliases && source ~/.zaliases
```

in your dotrc file.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for clarifying this.  In tcsh it's easy:

```
alias rmi 'ls * | grep -v \! | xargs rm -rf'
```

this should do it...

```
\!
```

expands all arguments following "rmi"

you could also use "find" to do this..

```
find . -type f | grep -v \! | xargs rm -rf'
```

... be careful with that axe! (rm -rf)