# How to make alias of a linux command

Tags: linux

/home/ABC/Ladoga

i want to make alias of that line as a **Ladoga ** so whenever i type the command 
**Ladoga ** it will execute the Ladoga command **/home/ABC/Ladoga**

Ladoga is basically a script file

Comment: `alias Ladoga=/home/ABC/Ladoga`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux alias question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600899/linux-alias-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Your home directory :-
cd ~

Edit .bashrc file in this directory :-
vi .bashrc

Add alias command by pressing i  :-
alias Ladoga='/home/ABC/Ladoga'

Save :-
[Esc] :x

Restart Terminal